# Extracting specific links from source code in linux command line

Tags: regex, text-editing

I have a 3000 line source code text file of a page. How I can extract specific urls similar to down below and delete rest source code ?

```
https://d17nygptf7ayu.cloudfront.net/photos/0b1983ccf6bb5674f93b.jpg
```

As I went thru code, there are 60 links similar to above link with only change in *.jpg names.

as a beginner I have least idea where to start and which tool I should use on linux  command line. Also how i can do this in notepad++?

Regex I come up with `https\://d17nygptf7ayu\.cloudfront\.net/photos/(?:(?!\.jpg)(?:.|\n))*\.jpg`

Comment: If the name is always 20 hex characters: `https\://d17nygptf7ayu\.cloudfront\.net/photos/[0-9a-f]{20}.jpg`, or if you want to allow anything before the `.jpg`: `https\://d17nygptf7ayu\.cloudfront\.net/photos/[^\.]+.jpg`

Comment: Yes, all images have 20 hex characters. But is there any tool to extract similar urls from a text file? I can do this in notepad++. But as beginner, I am looking for command line tool to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will match the URLs you want:

```
https\://d17nygptf7ayu\.cloudfront\.net/photos/[0-9a-f]{20}.jpg
```

The `[0-9a-f]` above matches any lower-case hex digit, and `{20}` matches exactly 20 of them.

The classic and oh-so-useful Linux tool that searches based on regular expressions is `grep`. One usually uses the `-E` flag, which causes it to use extended regular expressions. The `-o` flag causes it to output *only* the matching string. (Normally `grep` would output the entire line which contains the matching string.) For a full description of how to use `grep`, type `man grep`.

So to generate a list of all the matching URLs:

`grep -Eo 'https\://d17nygptf7ayu\.cloudfront\.net/photos/[0-9a-f]{20}.jpg' long_text_file.html >output_list_of_urls.txt`

Note that, if the file you list in place of `output_list_of_urls.txt` already exists, it will be overwritten. Also note that the regular expression is in quotes. If your input or output filenames contain spaces or other special characters, they need quotes too.

Comment: This is faster than doing it on notepad++. As I have more than 300 html files from where I wanted to extract.   ```for f in *.txt;do grep -E -o 'https\://d1a0n9gptf7ayu\.cloudfront\.net/photos/[0-9a-f]{32}.jpg' "$f" > "$(basename "$f" .txt)";done ``` took just 3 seconds.

Comment: One thing on notice that links are not in order same as in html file.

Comment: The links *should* be in the same order as in the input file; `grep` process the file from start to finish. Nice `for` loop, above. As an alternative, if you wanted the output combined in a single file, you could use `>>output_list_of_urls.txt` rather than `> "$(basename "$f".txt` and the output will be appended to that file.